# Как найти строку в файле а затем ее использовать Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пишу програму которая должна найти имя и счет тй:
с начала пользователь вводит имя, затем програма ищет его имя в файле, а затем из остатка строки делает счет. Строка должна выглядеть так  `Thomas 50`, моя проблема в том что я не могу найти и преобразовать строку в счет. Текстовый файл должен выглядеть так

```
Thomas 50
Elice 100
Tom 200
```

Comment: Никто не понял, что подразумевается под *счётом*. А алгоритм до ужаса прост должен быть: `for line in readlines(...): if line.startswith(name) ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну как  то  так  наверное:

```py
def get_score_for_name(path_to_file, name):
    score_out = []
    with open(path_to_file) as file_handler:
        for name_ in file_handler:
            name_list = name_.split()
            if name_list[0] == name:
                score_out.append(name_list[1])
    return score_out
```

где path_to_file  - путь  к вашему файлу, name - имя, по которому надо найти счет (если имен несколько выведет столько же значений счетов)